# Calling pthread_join with one argument causes a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, fault, continuous, pthread-join

If I call pthread_join continuously (without using other functions) it will cause a segmentation fault.

I can solve the problem by inserting a `sleep();` , `printf()` or anything else between two calls of pthread_join.

OS & GCC Version:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Complie command:

```
gcc demo_thread.c -lpthread  -o demo_thread.out
```

Source code (demo_thread.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *f1(void *);

int main() {
    int k = 2;
    pthread_t fa[k];
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        pthread_create(&fa[i], NULL, f1, NULL);  
    }

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        // printf("%ul\n", fa[i]); // uncomment this line, problem disapper.
        pthread_join(fa[i]);
    }
}

void *f1(void *arg) {
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
        printf("%d\n",i );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always check your error returns. If `pthread_create` fails it doesn't set your `fa[i]` to any valid value. I imagine you must set `k` very high because with just k = 2 there's no problem here.

Comment: I just set k = 2. And I can ensure that call to `pthread_create` success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you even make that compile? I just now realized you did not use `#include <pthread.h>` and you used one argument instead of two for `pthread_join`.

If I leave out the include I get

```
error: unknown type name ‘pthread_t’
```

And if I do include it then I get

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘pthread_join’
```

Oh I see that if I include `#include <stdlib.h>` and leave out `<pthread.h>` then it will have a definition for `pthread_t` but nothing for `pthread_join`. There are still plenty of warnings though:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_join’
```

You should always build programs with the `-Wall -W -pedantic` arguments to the compiler. And fix the warnings.

And to explain the crash: Since you don't pass NULL as the second argument to `pthread_join` it will be receiving a "random" value and then writing into it as if it was a pointer. Which it isn't. So it will either write a value into your allocated memory where it shouldn't, or it will get a segmentation fault.

And to explain how `printf` or `sleep` fixes the problem: Making those function calls must change the value of the `RSI` register (RSI is used for the second function argument) enough that it is either a valid pointer or NULL.

Comment: The way I compile the code is `gcc -g demo_thread.c -lpthread  -o demo_thread.out`. Maybe you miss the `-lpthread`.

Comment: @omar.zhou No I didn't miss it. I have a lot of automated stuff in my editor and Makefiles so at first I didn't even see the header was missing, because my editor had automatically added it, and removed stdlib.h since it was never used. And `-pthread` gets automatically added to the compiler flags.